# Reduce GCC output during installations

Tags: gcc

Every time I install software that gets built using GCC (in the "AUR" repository on my Arch-based system), I get many thousands or, on big packages, maybe even millions of screen pages of warnings that I am not at all interested in. It makes everything else in my console almost unreachable, because I have to jump back to the beginning and start scrolling down from there, because the scroll bar completely disappears into a <1px line. And it's also plain annoying and ridiculous.

If I was manually running `gcc`, I could simply append `-w`, but I'm not doing that, it's either done by `yay` or `pacman` or some installation script or who knows what. **Is there a way to just always enable `-w` for `gcc`, no matter what it is run from?**

(Apart from that, GCC-based installations also tend to be a LOT slower than any other ones, twice they have even taken over an hour, but I assume that cannot be fixed so easily.)

Comment: There is also some other type of output that is way too common during GCC installations, but I actually gave up trying to find it again after I had held Shift+PageUp for multiple minutes and saw nothing but warnings. I'm currently letting `xdotool` hold those keys for me, maybe I'll see it flying by. But probably not.

Comment: I found a screenshot of that other type of output spam: It starts similar to `libtool: compile:  x64_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DEXEEXT=\".exe\" -DEXEEXT=\".exe\" - DEXEEXT=}".exe\" -I. -I../../../gettext-tools/intl -I.. -I../../../gettext-tools` and so on, a long list of arguments to a command call. They all look very similar to each other, but they differ, for example some start instead with `/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC  --mode=compile x86_64-264-mingw32-gcc` and there are also variations in the arguments. There are phases with spam of that and much longer phases with warning spam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't specifically check whether the same package now spams less which spammed before, but I haven't had any update that caused my scroll bar to shrink to 1 pixel in weeks, so I guess this worked:

I edited `/etc/makepkg.conf`. There was already a line like this in there:

```
MAKEFLAGS="-j$(($(nproc)+1))"
```

I edited it to:

```
MAKEFLAGS="-j$(($(nproc)+1)) -w"
```

From `man gcc`:

```
    -w  Inhibit all warning messages.
```